# How to convert response of post request to bool in C#

Tags: c#, api, dynamics-crm

I have an endpoint with functionname (( `CallTrafficEndPoint` )) this request was developed by RestSharp Methdology

And I call this endpoint from other place in code but the retrieved type was (`RequestData`)

so How can I retrive a bool value from this request?

```
namespace Business.TrafficIntegration
{
    public static class Calling_API
    {
        public static RequestData CallTrafficEndPoint(RequestData TrafficModel, CrmDAL crmDal)
        {
            RequestData IsLicenseValid;
            Utility.Utility utility = new Utility.Utility(crmDal);
            string serviceURL = utility.GetAdminConfigurationValue("valid-licence");
            var client = new RestClient(serviceURL);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            var body = new RequestData();
            body = TrafficModel;
            request.AddJsonBody(body);
            

            using (MemoryStream DeSerializememoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Json String that we get from web api 
                var response = client.Post(request);
            
                //initialize DataContractJsonSerializer object and pass Student class type to it
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RequestData));

                //user stream writer to write JSON string data to memory stream
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(DeSerializememoryStream);
                writer.Write(response);
                writer.Flush();

                DeSerializememoryStream.Position = 0;

                //get the Desrialized data
                RequestData SerializedObject = (RequestData)serializer.ReadObject(DeSerializememoryStream);
                IsLicenseValid = SerializedObject;

               // throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("The retrieved value " + IsLicenseValid);

               return IsLicenseValid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need this code? It seems to have nothing to do with your question. The only relevant information would be the return type of the method `RequestData`, since you are asking after calling this method what to do with the return value.

Comment: @RandRandom yes exactly the return type of this method was RequestData and I need to find a way to convert it to a bool value